# It's possible to use Google Charts api in Android application offline?

Tags: android, google-visualization

i'm working on Android app to make graphs with Google Charts api. So my question is, it's possible to create these graphs without connecting with Google.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way using Google Charts because thier page are loaded dynamically!

> Can I use charts offline?
>   Your users' computers must have access to http://www.google.com/jsapi in order to use the interactive features of Google Charts. This is because the visualization libraries that your page requires are loaded dynamically before you use them. The code for loading the appropriate library is part of the included jsapi script, and is called when you invoke the google.load() method. Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.load or google.visualization code to use offline.

Source : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline